# To get consent from OAuth Consent

Tags: google-oauth, unauthorized, google-developers-console

I linked Google Drive from my ERP program.

Yet, from last February 20th, I can't sign in from the program.

I checked my domains from Search Console.

However, I still don't get a consent from OAuth Screen.

What should I do?

The below is the image from OAuth Consent Screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)
>
> An unverified app is a web application or Apps Script that requests a sensitive OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process. Users of unverified apps or your test builds might get warnings based on the OAuth scopes you're using. This is to protect users and their data from deceptive applications.

If you read the page you will see that your application has not completed the verification process as you have requested one or more of the sensitive scopes.

[image]

You have also not verified the domain

[image]

Only the developer who created the project will probably be able to login and with a limited quota.  You need to wait until the application is verified before it will begin work in a production mode.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

I requested for verification again.

Also, for unauthorized domain, I checked them in Google Search Console and solved related issues. 

From Google Search Console, it shows no error message.

But I still get exclamation mark. 

Do I need to check other things to verify my domains?

Comment: It probably will show an exclamation mark as its a required thing its not a warning mark.   as long as its in https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home then your good to go.